# Does dual boot affect booting time?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

My computer has both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, the latter of which I installed later. I wonder if completely deleting Windows could improve Linux booting time (about 1 min at the moment).

Below, the output of `systemd-analyze blame`, which I don't quite understand, although I know that dev/sda6 is where Linux is mounted on.

```
 25.369s dev-sda6.device
 17.412s systemd-udevd.service
 12.970s plymouth-quit-wait.service
  7.207s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  4.482s fwupd.service
  3.484s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  3.438s plymouth-start.service
  2.950s snapd.service
  2.681s apt-daily.service
  2.307s apparmor.service
  2.173s systemd-modules-load.service
  2.166s plymouth-read-write.service
  2.118s keyboard-setup.service
  1.945s NetworkManager.service
  1.739s accounts-daemon.service
  1.604s systemd-journald.service
  1.337s ModemManager.service
  1.281s sys-kernel-debug.mount
  1.252s dev-hugepages.mount
  1.251s dev-mqueue.mount
  1.230s avahi-daemon.service
  1.180s irqbalance.service
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My 10yo hdd only takes 10.45s, plymouth-quit-wait on mine doesn't appear so those alone make up 25+ seconds extra for you. I'd check the health of your hdd (mine shows 100% performance where I suspect yours doesn't; even if your [drive] health stats are ~okay), but replacing it can be $costly. The plymouth I suspect could be easily fixed...  (*dual booting should only had millisecs beyond the grub-menu time I'd believe*)

Comment: if the code is running fully in memory then no. If however the code calls library functions that need to be paged in from disk (libs not in memory & read from disk *or* paged-memory-on-disk) then yes.   If the program uses loads of memory, it could indirectly cause the OS or other running programs to have page-faults & jumps to disk too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should not have any impact on boot time in itself.  The only thing that could alter this is if you change the time that the boot menu shows for or prevent the boot menu showing at all.

I think your hard drive is relatively slow.

Comment: Agreed the HDD is really slow that it even shows up in the list tells everything, on my relatively slow SSD it is not even listed in the list and startup finishes on my system which is running an Apache server and the like only ~33 seconds. Guess best advice is to get a small SSD 120 GB or so to improve the boot time drastically.